# Backbone: Toggle methods on some event

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I want one button to toggle two methods in backbone but I'm having issues. I'm pretty much new to JS in general.

If you click on a button:

- I want to show a hidden div
- change the text of the button clicked

Then, if you click the button again (which has the new text and the hidden div is shown)

- Change the text
- Hide the shown div

The second method of .hide is not being fired? I'm wondering if this is because .hide is not in the DOM initially, because it's being added on the show method. Just a guess and maybe there's a better way to toggle methods on one class?

Here's my JS

```
'touchstart .share-btn' : 'show',
'touchstart .hide' : 'hide'


    'show' : function (e) {
        var view = this;

        $(e.currentTarget).closest('.tile').find('.share-tools').fadeIn('fast');
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass('hide');
        if ($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('hide')){
             $(e.currentTarget).find('.button-copy').closest('.button-copy').html('close');
        }

    },

    'hide' : function (e) {
        var view = this;
            if($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('hide')) {
            $('.share-tools').fadeOut('fast');
            $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('hide');
            $(e.currentTarget).find('.button-copy').closest('.button-copy').html('share');
        }

    },
```

Comment: I understand what you're going for, but what is the problem? Does the above code throw an error, or are you not seeing the desired behavior?

Comment: The second method of .hide is not being fired? I'm wondering if this is because .hide is not in the DOM initially, because it's being added on the show method. Thanks for helping!

Comment: You can see [in the backbone source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-138) that it is delegating the events to the view's root element, so it should register a click on `.hide` even if the class is added later.

Comment: The original issue was how current target was being defined. But now both methods are being called on the first click. Maybe it's best to start over. What is the best way to show an element if a selector is clicked, then listen again for a second click and execute different methods?

Basically I just need to understand how to show and hide based on clicking one button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe reworking your code a bit will help. I've created [a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somethingkindawierd/7rfs9/) based on what I think you're trying to accomplish.

Here is the relevant view code:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

    ...

    // Make it clear that these are the same element.
    // Ensure they will not both fire by making them exclusive.
    events: {
        'mousedown .share-btn:not(.hide)' : 'show',
        'mousedown .share-btn.hide' : 'hide'
    },

    'show' : function (e) {
        console.log('show');
        var $e = $(e.currentTarget);
        $e.closest('.tile').find('.share-tools').fadeIn('fast', function () {
            $e.addClass('hide');
        });
        $e.find('.button-copy').closest('.button-copy').html('close');
    },

    'hide' : function (e) {
        console.log('hide');
        var $e = $(e.currentTarget);
        $e.closest('.tile').find('.share-tools').fadeOut('fast', function () {
            $e.removeClass('hide');
        });
        $e.find('.button-copy').closest('.button-copy').html('share');
    }
});
```

You can find the working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/somethingkindawierd/7rfs9/

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return false in your event listener to prevent call both methods on first click.